# ¿Como lograr guardar datos en mi db desde php?

Tags: php, html5

llevo un par de dias tratando de guardar un formulario con el siguiente codigo php, cabe destacar que el mismo codigo me funcionó para registrar usuarios (obviamente cambie las varibles), pero no logro hacer que lo guarde y solo me marca error, soy nuevo en esto y es para un proyecto, gracias de antemano.

```
    <?php
session_start(); 
extract($_POST); //conexion a base de datos 
  $usuario = "root";
  $password = "";
  $servidor = "localhost";
  $basededatos ="bdsmart"; 
 $conexion =@mysqli_connect ($servidor,$usuario,"") or die ("No se ha podido conectar con el servidor de Base de datos"); 
$db =@mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die ("Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la Base de datos");

//Obtener datos

$titular = $_POST['Titular'];
$NumCard= $_POST['card'];
$mes= $_POST['fecha'];
$year= $_POST['fecha2'];
$cvv=$_POST['CVV'];

  //sentencia sql 
$sql=@mysqli_query("INSERT INTO transacciones (titular,num_card,mes_exp,año_exp,cvv) VALUES ('$_POST[Titular]','$_POST[card]','$_POST[fecha]','$_POST[fecha2]','$_POST[CVV]')");

  //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
   $ejecutar=@mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
   //verificacion de la ejecución
    if(!$ejecutar)
        {
         echo "Error";
        }
else {
    echo "Transaccion completada";
}
```

esta es la parte del formulario:

```html
</form>
<div class="form-group" id="Online">
  <form action="GuardarPago.php" class="form-group" method="post">
    <p class="mt-3 h3 text-center">Pago en linea</p>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label mr-2" for="customRadio1">Credito</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Debito</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <label for="Titular">Nombre del titular</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Titular" placeholder="Nombre" required>

    <label for="Card">Número de tarjeta</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="card" id="Card" placeholder="0044-0044-8523-5412" pattern="[0-9]{16}" maxlength="16" required>
    <div class="form-group row mt-3">
      <div class="col">
        <label for="Fecha">Fecha de expiración</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="fecha" required>
          <option value="01">Enero</option>
          <option value="02">Febrero </option>
          <option value="03">Marzo</option>
          <option value="04">Abril</option>
          <option value="05">Mayo</option>
          <option value="06">Junio</option>
          <option value="07">Julio</option>
          <option value="08">Agosto</option>
          <option value="09">Septiembre</option>
          <option value="10">Octubre</option>
          <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
          <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control mt-2" name="fecha2" required>
          <option value="19"> 2019</option>
          <option value="20"> 2020</option>
          <option value="21"> 2021</option>
          <option value="22"> 2022</option>
          <option value="23"> 2023</option>
          <option value="24"> 2024</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <label for="CVV">CVV</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="CVV" id="CVV" placeholder="123" pattern="[0-9]{3}" maxlength="3" required>
      </div>


    </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: @ es el operador de supresión de errores y oculta los avisos/errores que emite la función. Su uso se considera generalmente como una mala práctica. Te recomiendo eliminar el @ para que puedas ver los errores que este te arroja.

Comment: he quitado los @ y ahora me marca esto Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\wamp64\www\SmartFix\GuardarPago.php on line 22
Error

Comment: perdon por: "INSERT INTO transacciones (titular,num_card,mes_exp,año_exp,cvv) VALUES ('$titular','$card','$fecha','$fecha2','$CVV')";

Comment: Hola, puedes poner tu código completo? Falta el código del formulario, tal vez te está marcando el error por qué no tienes nada en los $_POST.

Comment: lo agregue al post. espero me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Al parecer el formulario está bien, el archivo PHP es el que se puede arreglar un poco. 
El principal error está en la parte del sql del `INSERT` En vez de `VALUES ('$_POST[Titular]','$_POST[card]',...` debe ser `VALUES ('$titular','$NumCard',...`
En PHP dentro de comillas dobles serán automáticamente evaluada las variables, excepto las que implican comillas internamente, por ejemplo `$_POST['Titular']`,  `$array1['color1']`, etc.

Otra cosa, es que no se aconseja usar ñ, ni dieresis (ë), ni tildes en los nombres de los campos de la base de datos, ni en las tablas, ni en las variables, ni en los nombres de archivo. Quizás PHP, Python y otros lenguajes que se actualizan muy seguido uno pueda hacer que trabajen bien con esos caracteres, pero con otras tecnologías pueden dar muchos problemas. Tu no sabes si a tu base de datos posteriormente se conecte un servicio desarrollado por terceros, como una reportería o un ERP, así que es mejor ir estandarizando bien esas cosas desde un principio.

El código con las mejoras debe quedar algo como esto:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
//conexion a base de datos 
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos ="bdsmart"; 
$mysql_conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $basededatos);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('No se pudo conectar con la base de datos: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset($mysql_conn, "utf8") // Posiblemente necesites esta linea por la "ñ" en un campo

//Obtener datos
$titular = $_POST['Titular'];
$NumCard= $_POST['card'];
$mes= $_POST['fecha'];
$year= $_POST['fecha2'];
$cvv=$_POST['CVV'];

//sentencia sql 
$query = "INSERT INTO transacciones (titular, num_card, mes_exp, año_exp, cvv) VALUES ('$titular','$NumCard','$mes','$year','$cvv')";
//ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysql_conn, $query);
//verificacion de la ejecución
if(!$resultado) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "Transaccion completada";
}

// [Opcional] Cierre explicito de la base de datos, aunque también se cierra sola al terminar el script
mysqli_close($mysql_conn);
```

Comment: GRACIAS, de verdad ya me estaba volviendo loco. De verdad muchas gracias, me sirvió a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que así queda mejor el form:

```
  <form class="form-group" method="post">
<p class="mt-3 h3 text-center">Pago en linea</p>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label mr-2" for="customRadio1">Credito</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Debito</label>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<label for="Titular">Nombre del titular</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Titular" placeholder="Nombre" required>

<label for="Card">Número de tarjeta</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="card" id="Card" placeholder="0044-0044-8523-5412" pattern="[0-9]{16}" maxlength="16" required>
<div class="form-group row mt-3">
  <div class="col">
    <label for="Fecha">Fecha de expiración</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="fecha" required>
      <option value="01">Enero</option>
      <option value="02">Febrero </option>
      <option value="03">Marzo</option>
      <option value="04">Abril</option>
      <option value="05">Mayo</option>
      <option value="06">Junio</option>
      <option value="07">Julio</option>
      <option value="08">Agosto</option>
      <option value="09">Septiembre</option>
      <option value="10">Octubre</option>
      <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
      <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control mt-2" name="fecha2" required>
      <option value="19"> 2019</option>
      <option value="20"> 2020</option>
      <option value="21"> 2021</option>
      <option value="22"> 2022</option>
      <option value="23"> 2023</option>
      <option value="24"> 2024</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <label for="CVV">CVV</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="CVV" id="CVV" placeholder="123" pattern="[0-9]{3}" maxlength="3" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar">

</div>
```

Como puedes ver quite el "action" del form y agregué el `<input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar">`, ahora asi debería de quedar tu código PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

  session_start(); 

  $usuario = "root";
  $password = "";
  $servidor = "localhost";
  $basededatos ="bdsmart";

  $conexion =mysqli_connect ($servidor,$usuario,$password) or die ("No se ha podido conectar con el servidor de Base de datos"); 

 $db =mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die ("Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la Base de datos");

//Obtener datos
  $titular = $_POST['Titular'];
  $NumCard= $_POST['card'];
  $mes= $_POST['fecha'];
  $year= $_POST['fecha2'];
  $cvv=$_POST['CVV'];   
  //sentencia sql 
 $sql="INSERT INTO transacciones (titular,num_card,mes_exp,año_exp,cvv) VALUES ('$titular','$NumCard','$mes','$year','$cvv')";

  //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
 $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
  //verificacion de la ejecución
  if(!$ejecutar){
   echo "Error";
  }
  else{
   echo "Transaccion completada";
  }
 }
```

Tu código no funcionaba ya que lo tenías asi:

```
$sql=@mysqli_query("INSERT INTO transacciones (titular,num_card,mes_exp,año_exp,cvv) VALUES ('$_POST[Titular]','$_POST[card]','$_POST[fecha]','$_POST[fecha2]','$_POST[CVV]')");
```

Y el mysqli_query debe de ir enla línea de abajo...

Ahora, para este ejemplo utilicé código que tu posteaste, solo me queda decir que tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques, deberías de probar usar "Prepared Statements" y algun tipo de sanitize al momento de hacer el $_POST.

Saludos!

Comment: desgraciadamente no funcionó, aunque no me marcó ningun error, de igual manera agradezco mucho tu tiempo. la respuesta de abajo me solucionó mi problema. Gracias

Comment: Hola Alan, que raro, a mí me funcionó perfecto, qué bueno que pudiste solucionarlo, saludos